# ACF Pro: Hidden Field does not get updated anymore

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In earlier versions of ACF Pro I could grab the selected value with javascript of a select2 field.
In an earlier release this 'feature' got removed.

`<input id="acf-field_590738c9b397c-input" name="acf[field_590738c9b397c]" value="" type="hidden">`

does not update the value anymore when changing the select2 field.

I am trying to accomplish setting defaults based on a selection.
Here is my Code:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    ;

    acf.add_action('ready', function ($input, args, settings, $field) {
        // console.log($input, args, settings, $field);
        // $input (jQuery) hidden input element
        // args (object) args given to the select2 function
        // settings (object) settings given to the acf.select2 function
        // $field (jQuery) field element

        var $field;
        $field = $('#acf-field_590738c9b397c-input');
        $field.on("change", function () {
            set_defaults($(this).val())
        });

        var defaultIntro=$('#default_intro').val();
        $('.acf-field-590778bbb66ff .acf-input').html(defaultIntro);
    });

    function set_defaults(value) {
        var val = $('#term_' + value).val();
        if (val) val = val.split(','); else val = [];

        $('[data-name="duties"] input[type="checkbox"],[data-name="bring_with"] input[type="checkbox"],[data-name="we_offer"] input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
            console.log($(this));
            if (val.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1)
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
            else
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The Hidden term_id fields work - I use this code to create them:

```
function my_acf_load_field($field)
{
    $terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'pz_job_position', 'hide_empty' => false,));
    if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $default_duties = is_array(get_field('default_duties', $term)) ? get_field('default_duties', $term) : [];
            $default_we_offer = is_array(get_field('default_we_offer', $term)) ? get_field('default_we_offer', $term) : [];
            $default_bring_with = is_array(get_field('default_bring_with', $term)) ? get_field('default_bring_with', $term) : [];
            $default = array_merge($default_duties, $default_we_offer, $default_bring_with);
            $default_terms = array();
            foreach ($default as $duty) {
                if (is_object($duty))
                $default_terms[] = $duty->term_id;
            }
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo join(',', $default_terms) ?>" id="term_<?php echo $term->term_id ?>">

            <?php

        }
    }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_field('default_job_intro', 'option'); ?>" id="default_intro">
    <?php

}
```

//edit:
The Problem is: Earlier the value of the described field was updated according to the selection and I could use my function. Now the value of input#acf-field_590738c9b397c-input does not get updated anymore nad $field.on('change', ()) does not trigger anymore on value change of the select2 field.

//EDIT2:

So what I am really trying to achieve is the following:
We have a lot of ongoing job offers as we are growing.
The person who is putting the jobs on our website should set the default requirements for the potential employee based on an job description.
So for example:

If we are hiring a new Front-Desk Manager the User can create a new 'Job Type' with default Duties, etc.

[image: The Job Manager can create a new Job Type here]

If there is already a Job description matching the new offered job, the job manager should only select the position in the backend:
[image: Job is created]
When the Position is selected, the default duties and so on should select automatically.
This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are having? I understand that you want to update the hidden fields but I'm not sure where your issue is.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I just updated the Question with a more specific Problem description.

Comment: I understand the problem now, but I don't see anything immediately obvious in the code. I'd suggest debugging the script in the browser to identify where exactly the issue ie - it onChange failing because the event isn't being triggered, or is `$field = $('#acf-field_590738c9b397c-input');` not even finding the select element? When you view the rendered html in the element inspector, can you see the select element hasn't somewhow been changed from `#acf-field_590738c9b397c-input`?

Comment: Hi @FluffyKitten, the value of the element doesn't get changed at all. So I assume ACF has changed something in their code. But I don't get how the value is transmitted on form send. Do you have any idea how to solve this differently?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve - could you maybe edit your question to explain? I assume you have a select that will change the values to be set in the ACF fields depending on whats chosen? ACF allows conditional fields so maybe you could do all that in the field group itself? I'd also suggest trying the on the ACF site if you need specialist help , especially if ACF have changed something themselves.